# ASP NET CORE MVC - How to binding data to spreadsheet

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, devexpress, spreadsheet

How to create spreadsheet with data on worksheet from list object ?
i using devexpress asp net core to create spreadsheet.

this is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Overview(IFormFile document)
        {
            var model = new DocumentModel();
            if (document != null)
            {
                //SaveFile(document);
                var stream = new MemoryStream();
                document.CopyTo(stream);

                //Office File API
                var workBook = new Workbook();
                workBook.LoadDocument(stream);
                //preprocess the uploaded file using Spreadsheet Document API

                model.DocumentId = document.FileName;
                model.ContentAccessorByStream = stream;
            }

            return View("Overview", model);
        }
```

How pass list to spreadsheet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to import your list with data into a worksheet:

```
// Import the list into the worksheet.
// Data starts with the B3 cell.
workbook.Worksheets[0].Import(yourList, 2, 1);
```

...or use Data Binding:

```
private void BindToRange(List<MyObject> dataSource, CellRange 
    bindingRange, Worksheet sheet) {

    // Specify the binding options.
    ExternalDataSourceOptions dsOptions = new ExternalDataSourceOptions();
    dsOptions.ImportHeaders = true;
    dsOptions.CellValueConverter = new MyObjectConverter();
    dsOptions.SkipHiddenRows = true;

    // Bind the data source to the worksheet range.
    WorksheetDataBinding sheetDataBinding = sheet.DataBindings.BindToDataSource(dataSource, bindingRange, dsOptions);

    // Adjust the column width.
    sheetDataBinding.Range.AutoFitColumns();
}
```

Please refer to the following articles to learn more info:

- [Example - How to Import Data To Worksheet](https://docs.devexpress.com/OfficeFileAPI/13777/spreadsheet-document-api/examples/data-import-and-export/how-to-import-data-to-a-worksheet)
- [Spreadsheet Document API - Data Binding](https://docs.devexpress.com/OfficeFileAPI/118785/spreadsheet-document-api/data-binding)
- [Spreadsheet Document API - Data Binding. API Reference](https://docs.devexpress.com/OfficeFileAPI/DevExpress.Spreadsheet.WorksheetDataBinding)

Comment: Thank you for tips